# PyQt Make on mac giving error

Tags: macos, build, makefile, installation, pyqt

When trying to get PyQt workin on a macbook (using snowleopard) I get the following error:

> warning: in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Python, missing required architecture x86_64 in file

I've installed:

1. xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg
2. Python 2.6.6
3. qt-mac-opensource-4.7.4
4. sip-4.12.4.tar.gz

all with success following 
[This Tutorial](http://blog.oak-tree.us/index.php/2010/05/27/pyqt-snow-leopard)

compiling PyQt is all fine but when I try make it I always get the above error.

Any ideas, examples, solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahha! It wasn't working coz apparently python 2.6.6 was compiled in a x64 environment this is why it was lookin for x64 type files. Using Python 2.7 x32 fixed this.

Here's what I did for anyone interested:

Note: for a x64 system, install python 2.7 x64 (suprise, suprise) and change all the "-arch=i386" to "-arch=x86_64"

#### 1. Instal Apple XCode

#### 2. Install Python 2.7 x32

#### 3. Install qt-mac-opensource-4.7.4.dmg

#### 4. Place sip-4.12.4.tar.gz and PyQt-mac-gpl-4.8.5.tar.gz on the desktop.

#### 5. Open terminal:

#### 6. In terminal, unzip files:

> > > tar xvfz sip-4.12.4.tar.gz
> > >
> > > tar xvfz PyQt-mac-gpl-4.8.5.tar.gz

#### 7. In terminal, build and install sip:

> > > cd sip-4.12.4
> > >
> > > python2.7 configure.py --arch=i386
> > >
> > > make
> > >
> > > sudo make install

#### 8. In terminal, browse back to the desktop:

> > > cd $HOME/Desktop

#### 9. In terminal, build and install PyQt:

> > > cd PyQt-mac-gpl-4.8.5
> > >
> > > python2.7 configure.py --use-arch=i386
> > >
> > > make
> > >
> > > sudo make install

#### 10. In terminal, test if pyqt is working:

> > > python
> > >
> > > import PyQt4

#### 11. DONE!!!